# Problem getting Stripe webhook to work in Stripe CLI

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using Stripe Checkout in an ASP.NET Web Forms app to let people pay for subscriptions, and that part of the code works fine.  I created a webhook with the following code:

```cs
using Stripe;
using Stripe.Checkout;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System;

namespace BNet {
    public class spdata : IHttpHandler {

        public void ProcessRequest ( HttpContext ctx ) {
            try {
                var epSecret = "whsec_u...";
                var json = new StreamReader(ctx.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
                FileOps.WriteFile ("~/files/output.txt", "testing", out _, out _ );
                var sig = ctx.Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"];
                try {
                    var se = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(
                    json,
                    sig,
                    epSecret
                );
                    if ( se.Type == "checkout.session.completed" ) {
                        var session = se.Data.Object as Session;
                        ProcessSubscription ( session );
                    }
                }
                catch ( StripeException e ) {
                    FileOps.WriteFile ( "~/files/StripeLog.txt", e.Message, out _, out _ );
                }
                catch ( Exception ex ) {
                    FileOps.WriteFile ( "~/files/ErrorLog.txt", ex.Message, out _, out _ );
                }
                ctx.Response.Write ( "ok" );
                ctx.Response.Flush ( );
            }
            catch (Exception exp) {
                ctx.Response.Write ( exp.Message );
            }
        }


        void ProcessSubscription (Session session) {
            FileOps.WriteFile ( "StripeLog.txt", session.ToString ( ), out _, out _ );
        }

        public bool IsReusable {
            get {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, I created an endpoint in Stripe to use this webhook, and when I run the app, the Dashboard returns a server status of 200 OK, but none of the code in the webhook ever fires.

Then, I set up Stripe CLI to test the webhook locally.  I use the following command to start CLI:

`stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:44357/spdata`

CLI gives me a secret key, which I copied into the webhook.  When I run the web app, it goes just fine.  But in the CLI window, here's what I get for every event Stripe fires back to me:

```
2021-06-08 15:38:23   --> checkout.session.completed [evt_1J0CctBQEZK85JIBn76jElzT]
2021-06-08 15:38:23            [ERROR] Failed to POST: Post "http://localhost:44357/spdata": read tcp [::1]:54739->[::1]:44357: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I don't know what the source of the error is.  I shut down Windows Firewall, and I don't have anything else running that could interfere.  Any help out there?

Comment: I don't know a lot about .NET routing, but don't you need to add something like `[Route("[controller]")]` to indicate the URL/path to your code just above your `public class` declaration?  If you add simple logging to the beginning of your function and try a simple POST request via curl, like `curl -v -X POST http://localhost:44357/spdata` does it log, or do you get an error/unexpected behavior/no log?

Comment: That's what you use when you're doing MVC, which this isn't.  (smile)  The code has a "WriteFile" call in several places that uses a custom function to write to a text file, and it doesn't even hit that code.  It's almost like it fails silently, and until or unless I can get the Stripe CLI to work, I can't debug it.  The big question is, why does Stripe CLI keep throwing all of the "Failed to POST" messages?  That's where I'm hoping someone who knows Stripe comes in!

Comment: Usually the error you're getting from Stripe CLI indicates your server code is refusing the connection.  That's why I suggested the `curl` test, to see if that's also rejected, or if it's something specific to Stripe CLI.

Comment: I know ITS bit late. AS of 2023, stripe webhook ACCEPT only https. and also I am unable to make it works on the console they provide <code>stripe listen --forward-to https_url

Answer (score 7):

I might be late, but change this from this

```
stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:44357/spdata
```

to this

```
stripe listen --forward-to https://localhost:44357/spdata
```

Stripe will only post on **https.**

Note: if you don't specify the protocol, like this `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:44357/spdata` (which is how it is done in the docs) it will default to http and will not work with just a generic error of `FAILED TO POST`

Comment: Subtracting 1, This post assumes the local https certificate will be trusted by the stripe cli, _which it will not be by default_, and will lead to another error: `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Comment: @MDMoore313 - to get around your certificate issue, add `--skip-verify` to the `listen` CLI command. e.g. `stripe listen --forward-to https://localhost:44357/spdata --skip-verify`

Comment: `http` works in test mode

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't figure out why I was not getting webhooks through the CLI either, until I removed the http:// from the '--forward-to' parameter. Then I suddenly started getting them.

Try this:
`stripe listen --forward-to localhost:44357/spdata`

(Note: I never even got the errors like you did - maybe I'm on an earlier CLI version?)

Answer (score 1):

Use `--skip-verify` in addition to pointing stripe to the https port to get it to work. `stripe listen` won't POST to an http port, as one answer correctly stated.

However, if stripe doesn't trust your local TLS certificate (it does *not* by default), then calling the webhook will fail when it tries to establish the TLS handshake.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely obvious for most of us, but I was tricked by it:

Make sure, your controller action is not restrcited by some authorization.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
```

Symptom: you see Status Code `302`, which is the redirect to the login page

That having said, Plain HTTP (without HTTPS) seems to work now, in a testing environment.